# Zend framework 2 static adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can I construct a static adapter to call in each controller action

```
$this->dbAdapter
```

instead of doing it everytime

```
like $this->getServiceManager()->get('dbAdapter');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the database adapter into your controller using a controller factory. This will allow you to reference it as a class property (`$this->dbAdapter`).

```
namespace Module\Factory;

use Module\Controller\FooController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

public class FooControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    protected $dbAdapter;

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $cpm)
    {
        $serviceManager = $cpm->getServiceLocator();

        // inject 'db1' or whatever your adapter's
        // name is registered as
        return new FooController($serviceManager->get('db1'));
    }
}
```

Register the factory with the controller plugin manager by adding an entry to your module class. If you already have an 'invokable' with the registered name then you will need to remove it.

```
class Module 
{    
    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Module\Controller\Foo' => 'Module\Factory\FooControllerFactory'
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Lastly allow the adapter into the controller via it's constructor.

```
use Zend\Db\AdapterInterface;

class FooController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $dbAdapter;

    public function __construct(AdapterInterface $dbAdapter)
    {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // now you can use the adapter in any action!
        $this->dbAdapter->doStuff();
    }

}
```

With all that done, I would strongly recommend against the above design (by this I mean injecting the adapter). This is due to the fact that you will be executing queries within the controller, a mix of domain logic with controller workflow. If your domain requirements change, your controller will also have to.

Comment: I'm not doing queryies from the controller, but colleagues of mine who build the model classes, required the db adapter to be passed in the constructor